# Do any launchers restore home screen widgets from Google backup?

Tags: app-widgets, launcher, restore

Are there any custom/3rd-party launchers that, when you have **Back up my data** turned on in the **Backup & reset** settings, restore home screen widgets when a backup is restored? I know the stock one doesn't, so I hope that someone with more experience of 3rd-party launchers will recognise the behaviour.

Comment: Although the question is off-topic, did you get the solution?

Comment: @Firelord No, I still don't know of any launchers that do this.